# Extracting filenames from a URL by splitting a string

Tags: array, vba

I am used to accessing items from an array, returned by the `Split` function, directly. This is lazy, I know. Usually, I know the element I want and I say something like:

```
Debug.Print Split(href, "/")(0)
```

**Questions:**

1) Can I do something similar to access the UBound of the array returned?

2) What is the "best practice" way of doing things and why?

**Code:**

I wrote the following but it looks messy.

```
Sub Testing()

    Dim href As String
    Dim fileName As String

    href = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/20180111-AmbSYS-post-ARP-month-of-December-2017v2.xlsx"

    fileName = Trim$(Split(href, "/")(UBound(Split(href, "/"))))

End Sub
```

I saw from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260982/how-to-find-number-of-occurences-of-slash-from-a-strings) that I can also do:

```
Debug.Print Split(href, "/")(Len(href) - Len(Replace(href, "/", "")))
```

Again, messy.

I know that I can assign to an array variable and then access the UBound that way. It looks tidier but is essentially the same thing; i.e.

```
Dim myArr() As String

myArr() = Split(href, "/")
fileName = myArr(UBound(myArr))
```

Comment: @Donald.McLean Neither myself or IvenBach bothered to point out the inconsistency in the variable name.  So I agree with the OP that the variable name should fixed.

Comment: @ThomasInzina We have a bot scanning for possible answer invalidations, sometimes a question is rolled back when it's not necessary, I agree that no rollback was needed this time and therefore rolled it back again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract the implementation into a function. This makes it easy to catch mistakes if you want to use this capability in more than one location. `GetUpperBoundElemenentFromDelimitedString` takes the required arguments you give it and returns the `UBound` result. The name may be cumbersome but typing `getup` and then pressing Ctrl+J will 'List Properties/Methods', the same going to Edit and choosing that option.

```
Public Function GetUpperBoundElemenentFromDelimitedString(ByVal inputValue As String, ByVal delimiter As String, Optional ByVal compare As VbCompareMethod = VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare) As String
    Dim temp As Variant
    temp = Split(inputValue, delimiter, compare:=compare)
    GetUpperBoundElemenentFromDelimitedString = temp(UBound(temp))
End Function
```

Now when you are using it the descriptive name lets you immediately know what's happening.

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim bar As String
    bar = "This,is,going,to,return,an,element,at,a,specific,position."
    Debug.Print GetUpperBoundElemenentFromDelimitedString(bar, ",")
End Sub
```

The same could be done for a specific position

```
Public Function GetArrayElemenentFromDelimitedString(ByVal inputValue As String, ByVal delimiter As String, ByVal zeroBasedPosition As Long, Optional ByVal compare As VbCompareMethod = VbCompareMethod.vbTextCompare) As String
    GetArrayElemenentFromDelimitedString = Split(inputValue, delimiter, compare:=compare)(zeroBasedPosition)
End Function
```

Comment: I have accepted this as I think it will be useful over the longer term.

Comment: Creating methods from raw code will help in abstracting your code and make it clearer what's going on. A good rule of thumb for me is if a comment is needed to tell you what is going on it's time to refactor that usage into a respective Sub/Function.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently getting ready to post my next item for review. I have tried, with limited success IMHO,  to do some abstraction. I have thirty subs/functions in the code I hope to have reviewed. Admittedly quite a few are very short. Are there guidelines on how much code you can post on this site? Largest around 44 lines, average under 10 maybe.

Comment: Go for MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A wall of text spanning 10 pages isn't likely going to get very far. A brief explanation of what you attempted to do and the code that follows has a much likelier chance for an answer. Just make sure it works and is compilable. Since you used the VBA tag take a look at http://rubberduckvba.com/ as it'll help with code suggestions and refactoring. **NOTE**: I am a contributor to RD. Those contributions and spending time at our lovely pond https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking helped me answer your question.

Comment: I love RubberDuck. I use it every day and have on this code. I will re-read the MCVE. I guess I was unsure on any differences for code review as it is a program  I have created. It runs fine and does its job and I have documented what each part should do. Just not experienced at high standard coding practices and hence thought of posting for review. It is general pointers on error handling, structure, how I can convert those subs to functions that RD always complains about......

Comment: Stop by the pond and rubberduck out loud with us about refactoring and how to better structure VBA code you have.

Comment: @QHarr please disregard IvenBach's recommendation to post a MCVE on this site - MCVE's are great for Stack Overflow, but the devil is in the details, and reviewing examplified code tends to, well, end up closed as off-topic "hypothetical/example code".

Comment: Ok. Would code posted in documented blocks of the approximate dimensions I describe above be ok? I don’t plan on just dumping a load of code. Rather a short précis of what the code does and outline of the flow. A few  images to show before and after state of the data being manipulated. The data is web scraped so publicly available and the program scrapes the data. All that is needed to run the code is a few matching named sheets in a workbook. Also, means call stack can be viewed at any point to clarify flow.

Comment: And 3 named folders on a desktop (public constants so easily modified to test folders).

Comment: @QHarr CR has *double* the post size capacity of any other SE site, including Stack Overflow ;-) rule of thumb, if it fits within ~60K characters and it's reasonably described, then it's fine. Basically, the paradigm is entirely different on this site, vs. on SO; see [this meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) for more information.

Comment: @Mat'sMug  Many thanks. I will review the link and set about drafting my post early next week.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the Array then then this is the best practice.

```
Dim FileName As String, myArr() As String
myArr() = Split(href, "/")
FileName = myArr(UBound(myArr))
```

Here are several different ways of returning the substring after the last delimiter and the time that it takes to run each 1 million times:

```
FileName = Right(href, Len(href) - InStrRev(href, "/")) ' 1.25 seconds
FileName = Mid(href, InStrRev(href, "/") + 1) ' 1.29 seconds
FileName = Split(href, "/")(UBound(Split(href, "/"))) '8.93 seconds
myArr() = Split(href, "/"):FileName = myArr(UBound(myArr)) ' 8.71 seconds
FileName = Split(href, "/")(Len(href) - Len(Replace(href, "/", "")))' 9.1 seconds
```

Notice that **InstrRev** is almost 7 times faster than using the **Split** methods.

Comment: Thank you. Really helpful. I will actually use this in my current project due to the speed implications and for the fact that I only care about the last delimited substring.